# Updating application settings in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, app-config, application-settings

I'm trying to update a value in my app.config file using the code below (the value is defined in Properties > Settings as Application scoped)

```
System.Configuration.Configuration configApp = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
MessageBox.Show(configApp.AppSettings.Settings.Count.ToString()); //this shows 0
configApp.AppSettings.Settings["PontajAdminPwd"].Value = "dsfs";
configApp.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
```

but it saying that configApp.AppSettings.Settings is empty...

This is a part of my app.config file

```xml
<applicationSettings>
    <PontajWPF.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="PontajAdminPwd" serializeAs="String">
            <value>696W3oybVP85szuiY2Qpiw==</value>
        </setting>
    </PontajWPF.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

EDIT 1: I'm in a hurry so I adopted the solution proposed here (direct file access after changing the app.config file by hand - using appSettings instead of applicationSettings):
http://www.longhorncorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/update-app-config-key-value-at-run-time-in-wpf/

Comment: Unless its just me but you probably don't need the OpenExeConfiguration if you just use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Comment: @hyp it is the same thing, Amar Palsapure it's right about the fact that it is not searching the right location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`configApp.AppSettings.Settings.Count.ToString()` this will try to read settings from `<appSettings>` section, not `<applicationSettings>`. Also the name of the file should `app.config`.

In your case you will need to use `Properties.Settings` static class, to access your settings from `applicationSettings`. You can try `PontajWPF.Properties.Settings.Default.PontajAdminPwd`

> **Application-scope settings are read only**, and can only be **changed at design time** or **by altering the .exe.config file in between application sessions**.
>
> **User-scope settings**, however, can be written at run time, just as you would change any property value. The new value persists for the duration of the application session. You can persist changes to user settings between application sessions by calling the Settings.Save method. These settings are saved in the User.config file.

Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#settingscs_topic3)

Hope this helps.

Comment: app.config is the name of the file and it is autogenerated by VS. configApp object doesn't have any member with the name applicationSettings,  any other way to edit them?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Application-Scope settings (which you are using) are read only when you are executing the application. Instead of using application-scope settings, use user-scope settings, if you are willing to modify the values.

Comment: Unfortunately PontajWPF.Properties.Settings.Default.PontajAdminPwd is read-only. You are right about initial statement, I used the code in another application (winforms) where the tags in app.config were indeed "<appSettings>" and there the code works. So, do you know if it is possible to change the tag?

Comment: Try this Properties => Settings, change the `PontajAdminPwd` scope from `Application` to `User`. And then do Settings.Default.PontajAdminPwd = "new password";

Comment: It is not an option for me to change the scope of those values. I will try to find out how it is done in WPF because in WinForms it is working...

Comment: Again let me tell you. When I did this experiment, the values which were assigned to `PontajAdminPwd` didn't reflect in config file which is with the executable. I guess it creates a local copy in `Users` may be `AppData`. If you get any solution do let me too. It will be great learning for me too. Thanks.

Comment: I modified the question with a temporary solution